# Dimension for Provinces of Spain

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have a report that is populated by different platforms (Salesforce, DB etc.) and now we are going to add `Analytics` data to that.
In our report for Spain, we use '[Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Spain)' values (Madrid, Barcelona, Málaga).

When I am getting data from Google Analytics, there are dimensions: `Region` and `City` but the problem is, values of `Region` are *Autonomous Communities+Cities* and values of  `City` are *Municipalities*.

Is there any field/dimension I can use to group my data by Provinces?

Comment: There is a non-ideal solution coming to mind which is mapping `City` values to respective *Provinces* but as a non-Spanish guy, getting the matching names of a list of Municipalities is almost impossible (even for a province, Biscay, Bizkaia (Basque), Vizcaya are all the same place, just localized wordings). If there is a file (json etc.) that has this kind of mapping, that can be useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in dimension for that. All you can do is to build an almost 100% matching table using Google Ads geo targets table from here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting
the underlying table 
(consider checking for proper language version)

Comment: Waited couple days to see if there would be another answer hence the delay of acceptance. Thanks for the reply and suggestion.